# Do I get an Integer or int after putting an int into an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, integer

Would (1) `int a; new Object[] {a}` be the same as (2) `new Object[] {new Integer(a)}` ?
If I do the 1st one, will `(new Object[]{a})[0]` give me an `Integer`?
thank you

Comment: You can test your second question.

Comment: @Vishal: That is how array literals are defined in Java.

Comment: @Syntactic: Thanks, I think its been ages I used arrays! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and yes.

You can't actually put an `int` into an `Object[]`. What you're doing is making use of a feature of Java called *autoboxing*, wherein a primitive type like `int` is automatically promoted to its corresponding wrapper class (`Integer` in this case) or vice versa when necessary.

You can read more about this [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

**Edit:**

As Jesper points out in the comment below, the answer to your first question is actually not "yes" but "it depends on the value of `a`". Calling the constructor `Integer(int)` as you do in (2) will *always* result in a new `Integer` object being created and put into the array.

In (1), however, the autoboxing process will not use this constructor; it will essentially call `Integer.valueOf(a)`. This *may* create a new `Integer` object, or it *may* return a pre-existing cached `Integer` object to save time and/or memory, depending on the value of `a`. In particular, values between -128 and 127 are cached this way.

In most cases this will not make a significant difference, since `Integer` objects are immutable. If you are creating a very large number of `Integer` objects (significantly more than 256 of them) and most of them are between -128 and 127, your example (1) will be probably be faster and use less memory than (2).

Comment: Not exactly; autoboxing does not use `new Integer(...)`, but `Integer.valueOf(...)` which is slightly different. Note that `Integer.valueOf(...)` doesn't always return a new `Integer` object; it has a cache for values between -128 and 127.

Answer (score 0):

What happens under the hood is Java compiler adds code like Integer.valueOf(a) in order to convert your int value into an Object.